# Debugging 400 when using VirtualHost with custom hostname (apache)

Tags: apache, virtualhost

This setup was working on an ubuntu 14.04 until a recent update (probably the update/ change in package itself is old).

- An internal DNS resolves "piwik.7l" to 192.168.1.17 .
- 192.168.1.17 serves an apache with piwik on it and following conf

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "piwik.7l"
    ServerAlias www.piwik.7l
</VirtualHost>
```

The setup now does work if addressed by IP, but responds with a 400 Bad Request if browsed to via its domain (piwik.7l). The 400 page does contain 
`Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at piwik.7l Port 80` and after setting the LogLevel to debug, I see following messages in the `error.log`:

```
[Mon May 22 15:12:33.566249 2017] [core:debug] [pid 1559] vhost.c(794): [client 192.168.1.112:38587] AH02415: [strict] Invalid host name 'piwik.7l', problem near: .7l
[Mon May 22 15:12:33.566316 2017] [core:debug] [pid 1559] vhost.c(889): [client 192.168.1.112:38587] AH00550: Client sent malformed Host header: piwik.7l
[Mon May 22 15:12:33.566326 2017] [core:debug] [pid 1559] protocol.c(1356): [client 192.168.1.112:38587] AH00569: client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /
```

In scroll-friendly

```
[strict] Invalid host name 'piwik.7l', problem near: .7l
AH00550: Client sent malformed Host header: piwik.7l
AH00569: client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /
```

I tried various combinations of IP, port and domain name usage in the VirtualHost/ServerName/ServerAlias blocks and disabled all other VirtualHost-definitions.

To me it sounds as if Apache would try to validate the "`tld`" part of the domain (`7l`) in a strict way. Is there any way I can disable that or debug it further?

**Edit**
The relevant parts of `apache2ctl -S`:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   piwik.7l (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
```

**Edit 2**
    `ping piwik.7l` does resolve fine from the webserver and from my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @savedarios answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/658537/apache-virtualhost-error-invalid-host-name/841984#841984

If found the solution to be the following change to my apache2.conf:

```
HttpProtocolOptions Unsafe
```